# Combining 2 different symbologies in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, fields-attributes

I've got a layer (road axis) with 2 different attributes : one with the amount of trafic, another with the number of people living next to this road. As symbology for the trafic amount, I like use different thicknesses. For the number of people, I want to use a different colors. How can I make a combination of these 2 symbologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of ways to achieve this I think but I will mention a couple:

- ### Rule-based style

Right-click your layer and go to *Layer Properties > Style* and change **Single Symbol** to **Rule-based**. Here you can add multiple symbology layers by clicking on the "plus" sign indicated by the red circle. You can specify the symbol, its attributes such as size and overall appearence, and you can set **rules** to determine which symbology according to the attribute of each feature. *Note that "Traffic" and "Residents" are the name of the attribute fields*.

[image: Rule-based style]

---

- ### Graduated style

Right-click your layer and go to Layer Properties > Style and change Single Symbol to **Graduated**. Here you can specify **one** field/column and easily create a series of symbololgy layers each according to a *range of values*:

[image: Graduated style]

Note that using *Graduated* (or *Categorized*) only affects one field. You would need to **duplicate** your layer and repeat the same steps for your second field.

Comment: My preference goes to a Graduated or Categorized symbology. Will I get a mix/merge of the two symbologies when duplicating the layer? Or will I have just two different symbologies lying upon each other?

Comment: @DavidM. - You would basically have the two symbologies from two layers lying upon each other. You could control which layer symbology should overlap the other by setting the **Layer Order**.

Comment: I've tried this, but it is not what I'm looking for. I really want to present my traffic intensity by a certain thickness and than giving these lines a certain color in function of the number of people living next to it.

Comment: @DavidM. - If you use **Rule-based style**, you can set up rules like `"Traffic" < 50 AND "Residents" > 2`. This style allows you to create symbols based on values from **multiple** fields insead of just one.

Comment: This seems to work, not that automated, but I've got the result that I need, Thanks!

Comment: @DavidM. - Most welcome buddy! Glad you got the result you need :)